# python-setuptools pkg_resources.py SyntaxError: invalid token

Tags: python, setuptools

Got this error on installing Python as usual on my workstation @ work (Windows environment):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\django-admin.py", line 4, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 29
    def _bypass_ensure_directory(name, mode=0777):
                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

I've been unable to find anything on searchengines, only some Debian related bugs.

I've tried reinstalling python-setuptools both via easy_install and the MSI installers (setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7).

Answer (score 2):

You are somehow running `django-admin.py` under Python 3. The octal literal syntax was changed in Python 3. The error you get is Python 3 complaining about Python 2.x octal literal syntax.

How do you invoke `django-admin.py`? You are somehow invoking `django-admin.py` in such a way that Python 3 is used.

Perhaps you do `c:\whatever> django-admin.py ...`?

In that case, I suggest try instead:

```
c:\whatever> c:\Python27\python.exe c:\Python27\Scripts\django-admin.py ...
```

The problem is probably that you have installed Python 3 after you installed Python 2. The Windows Python installer associates .py files for execution with the installed version.